# C++ learning header files. What's up with this semicolon?

Tags: c++, header, header-files

I'm learning to make header files. Here's my code (three separate files)

```
//Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.h"
;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << multiply(3, 4) << endl;

    return 0;
}

//functions.cpp
int multiply(int x, int y)
{
    return x * y;
}

//functions.h
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_
#define FUNCTIONS_H_

int multiply(int x, int y)

#endif
```

The code compiles and runs, but the part that's bothering me is in Main.cpp. There's that semicolon under "functions.h" and above "using namespace."

I put it there because visual studio said it was expecting one, but I have no idea why. I don't see it in tutorials.

Sure, it works. But I don't like not knowing why it's there and that it shouldn't be.

Comment: Since you're learning C++, please also learn to just fully qualify types / functions in the standard library. Typing `std::` is not that tedious.

Comment: Just did a little reading about that. Makes sense that you wouldn't namespace a header file. But would you say there's a practical use to omitting it in my personal test coding? (aside from habit forming)

Comment: You didn't add @Praetorian so he/she probably didn't see your question.  The issue of 'using namespace' statements tends to be a religious debate full of opinion, and my religious opinion is that for small programs, it's perfectly fine.  And if you're the only one who will ever work on it, do whatever the heck you please.  But as you noted, do watch out for developing bad habits.

Comment: @CareyGregory Ah, if I had read the help bar I would have known that. Thanks. That seems like a good approach to the subject btw

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because you miss one semicolon in functions.h

```
int multiply(int x, int y);
                          ^^^^ here
```

C++ separates statements with a semicolon.

The `#include directive`
causes the contents of the "functions.h" file to be sent along with the contents of your file to the compiler. The result of this is that compilation errors caused by mistakes in header files are often reported in the code which includes them.(thx to Philipp)

Comment: AH! I knew it would be something stupidly simple. Thanks a lot! Works now :)

Comment: What should be pointed out: the include directive in C++ means nothing else but "copy and paste the contents of that file here". The result of this is that compilation errors caused by mistakes in header files are often reported in the code which includes them.

Comment: You mean like I said in my answer? But because I had to type that, I didn't get there first.

Comment: @MatsPetersson First rule of rep whoring stack exchange: Trivial questions = tons of free rep, but only when you are quick enough. Speed > Quality.

Comment: Indeed, especially just after midnight, before you max out on reps for the day ;)

Comment: Haha well thank you both for your answers. I have a better understanding of why things work. If I could give you rep I would ;)

Comment: One time I got +4 for a quick answer which some commenter pointed out was complete bullshit (and he was right), but those who weren't really reading the question (just like me) didn't notice and upvoted me anyway.

Comment: @Philipp I especially appreciate the 20k+ rep mongers verbally (textually?) chewing out the underlings about posting an incomplete answer before their *initial* submit, only to see said-same ass-hat spamming a dozen updates in the first 5-min to their own hastily submitted answers on the next "trivial" question that comes along. You're absolutely right. Correct all-too-often takes a backseat to Quick.

Answer (score 6):

Since the C preprocessor knows nothing about the syntax of C at all - you can use it to put together emails, assembler source files or HTML if you like, it just puts all the source in one long file for the compiler to actually compile.

And you are missing a semicolon after `int multiply(int x, int y)` in "functions.h".